# Merge the [salutations] tag to the [greetings] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We should merge [salutations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salutations) (1 question) to [greetings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greetings) (3 questions) and make the former a synonym for the latter.  (Currently there are not enough high-rep users to do this without moderator actions.)

Comment: In the cases where we don't have enough high rep users I have been putting the same text in each tag and included boilerplate text about the intention to merge with which tag.

Comment: @YOU: Thanks! .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was completed (we like to have an answer so this does not show up as unanswered..)